# Python: while followed by elif

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, syntax

I thought `else if` and `elif` are logically identical.

But when I try `elif` after `while`, I get a syntax error.

However, `else` is OK after `while`, as shown here (see comments A & B):

```
MENU_COMMANDS = {
'goal': 'the objective of the game is .... ',
'close': 'exit menu',
'menu': 'show all menu commands',
'quit': 'quit game' }

GAME_KEYBOARD = {
'1': 1,
'2': 2 }

def turn1():
key = input("Player 1, make your move")  # == 'goal'

while key in MENU_COMMANDS:
    menu(key)
    key = input("after exiting the menu, make your move")
else:  # why not 'elif' ?    COMMENT A
    if key not in GAME_KEYBOARD:
        print("invalid move")
        return False

# elif key not in GAME_KEYBOARD:  # why won't this work? :(    COMMENT B
#     print("invalid move")
#     return False
```

Is this the only way to execute this logic, or is there a better one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elif: ...` is equivalent to `else: if: ...` in the context of an `if` block, but the `else` in a `while` block has an entirely different meaning from the `else` in an `if` block, so the two aren't interchangeable even though they're represented by the same keyword.

The `else` in this code block is unnecessary anyway:

```
while key in MENU_COMMANDS:
    menu(key)
    key = input("after exiting the menu, make your move")
else:  # why not 'elif' ?    COMMENT A
    if key not in GAME_KEYBOARD:
        print("invalid move")
        return False
```

Since you never `break` your `while`, there's no circumstance under which you'd end the loop and *not* enter the `else`.  Hence you can just remove the `else` and it should behave the same:

```
while key in MENU_COMMANDS:
    menu(key)
    key = input("after exiting the menu, make your move")

if key not in GAME_KEYBOARD:
    print("invalid move")
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

For loop control, `else` is a special case vs standard conditional statement.

> When used with a loop, the else clause has more in common with the else clause of a try statement than it does with that of if statements: a try statement’s else clause runs when no exception occurs, and a loop’s else clause runs when no break occurs.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

```py
>>> c = 0
>>> while c < 10:
...    break
... else:
...    print("caught a break")
...
>>> while c < 10:
...    c+=2
... else:
...    print("no break")
...
no break
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if a:
    do something
elif b:
    do something
elif c:
    do something 
else:
    ouch
```

is the same as

```
if a:
    do this
if (not a) and b:
    do that
if (not a) and (not b) and c:
    do these
if (not a) and (not b) and (not c):
    no
```

Comment: same in what sense? you should eloabaraete. in first, at most 3 is checked, in second, all 4.

Comment: The fourth one in the second has the same function as `else`